# Debugging modified OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I would like to modify OpenSSL code and then debug it in my IDE (`QTCreator`).

I have downloaded the OpenSSL source code, built it according to `./config` with debugging symbols, and deployed it in non-system folder. Still, when I make modifications to the library, the changes are not effective in the debugged program.

For instance, I attempt to modify handshake process and test the results using the `s_client` app. Nevertheless, the `s_client` app points to the system version of OpenSSL. Namely, `s_client` includes `<openssl/...>` (which is located in `/usr/local/...`).

I would like it to point to the just installed/modified version of openssl in different folder. There's a catch though. I have figured only one way how to do it, by modifying the original OpenSSL makefile, which is just huge and the task seems overwhelming.

Does anyone has any idea how to approach this issue? Please note that I would like to keep the system version of the OpenSSL operational (symbolic link not suitable).

I run the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The output of `ldd /my/version/of/openssl` is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd9a3d6000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f04523f8000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f0451f6a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0451d4d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0451983000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f045177f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0452668000)
```

Comment: What OS?  How do you start your version of `openssl s_client ...`?  Assuming you're running on Linux, post the output from `ldd /your/version/of/openssl`.

Comment: I assume you are loading system version of libssl and libcrypto. You can execute something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/libraries /your/version/of/openssl s_client ...`

Comment: Hi, I've printed the output of `ldd` command to the original post. I understand that it loads the system libraries, just as I expected. I see the trick with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, yet, it does not work for some reason.

Comment: What is the result of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` try?

Comment: Okey, further update. Using `export` command, I successfuly set the Library path in such a way, that `ldd` command shows desired version of the openssl library. It appears though that I am facing another issue. If I perform any change to the code inside `s_client` app of `openssl` (the app I am using for debugging), those can be seen in the binary. Nevertheless, any changes to openssl library code are not visible. Stated differently, it appears that the modified openssl binary still calls different openssl library files. Is this even possible?

Comment: It sounds like you are still calling default openssl application instead of your modified openssl app.

Comment: Agreed. But `ldd` command called on the binary shows path to the modified librariries. I'm kind of stuck here, hehe...

Comment: Do you call openssl using full path, `./openssl`, or just `openssl`?

Comment: Holy sh.... Such a dumb mistake. Of course I was calling `openssl`. Now, calling `./openssl' and everything is just fine (naturally). Thank you a lot for your help, the trick with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was still needed. I'll post the tricks that led to solution in the evening (and claim it as answer) for the future generations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the two guys (see comments), I was able to figure out the problem. First, make sure you compile `OpenSSL` with `--prefix` and `--openssl` directories properly set.

Once OpenSSL installed, you need your code (apps of `OpenSSL`) to be calling/linking your new version of `OpenSSL`. In `QtCreator` you can achieve this by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory with the library files `libcrypto.so.1` and `libssl.so.1`. The setting is done in `Projects -> Run environment -> (add LD_LIBRARY_PATH into system environment)`.

Moreover, you can check what libraries are called by the binary manually, by entering the directory with the binary and calling command `ldd ./openssl` from the terminal. This way, you will see what libraries are called (it should be your own version, not the system libraries). Further, you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from terminal, optionally with `export` command in front of it, to achieve permanent effect (lasting whole terminal session). In total, you could call

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/lib`.